# How to send a text message to a whatsapp group using social sharing plugin

Tags: c#, android, ionic-framework, ionic4, whatsapp

I'm developing an ionic app, which could send a text message to a group in **WhatsApp**. I'm already able to send a text message to an individual by using below code :

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(this.contactNo,this.text, null, null).then(() => {
  // Success
}).catch((e) => {
  // Error!
});
```

However, I cannot find any support in [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/social-sharing/) provided by Ionic to send a text message to a group.

Is there any workaround for sending a text message to a whatsapp group using social sharing plugin? If Yes, Please do share!

**OR**

If no, Is there any other plugin in ionic 4 which could help me send a text message to a whatsapp group?

Any help will be **deeply** appreciated as my manager is getting angry on me :/

**Update:**

If the above is not possible, my back-end is a Web API on C#, Is there any way to achieve the above goal using C# ?